# search and replace first two octets of a list of IPs using sed

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, ip

I was trying the below regex but it fails to match somehow and doesn't change all the IP addresses in the file.

`sed -i 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/23.243./' host.65k`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `sed -i -E 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/23.243./' host.65k`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!